# Why I can't see glyphicon icons in new opened window?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I open new window with help of  $window.open command and write html content to the window.

Here is Javascript code:

```
var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.controller('testController', ['$compile', '$scope','$window', function($compile, $scope, $window) {
    $scope.openWindow = function() {
       $window.open('', '_blank', 'width=500,height=400').document.write($("#report").html());
    };}]);
```

Here is content that I write to the new window:

```
<div ng-app="test" id = "report" ng-controller="testController">
 <p>Envelope icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></p>
<p>Search icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></p>
<p>Print icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></p>
<hr/>
    <button ng-click="openWindow()">push!</button>
</div>
```

And here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/281/).

The problem is that I cant see glyphicon icons in new opened window.

Any idea why I cant see glyphicon icons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two errors in your code. First you are not including the css correctly. You should use the `href` attribute instead of `rel` attribute to include the css. Second you have to use the `integrity` key check if you are including bootstrap from outside.

The correct inclusion is this one:

```
var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.controller('testController', ['$compile', '$scope','$window', function($compile, $scope, $window) {
    $scope.openWindow = function() {
    var content = $("#report").html();

    var html = '<html><head><title>hi</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"></head><body>'+content+'</span></p></body></html>'   

       $window.open('', '_blank', 'width=500,height=400').document.write(html);                         
    };}]);
```

And the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/283/

If you wish to make reference to the stylesheet from your project you can load a page template with a query parameter like `http://yoursite.com/page.html?window=true`, then on `$window` load you specify the url with query param.

```
$window.open('http://yoursite.com/page.html?window=true', '_blank', 'width=500,height=400');
```

Depending how you will load the template file (from backend for example) you can restrict to load the template file if query param exists.

Comment: thanks.But what if I want to make reference to style sheet from my project and not from the internet?

Answer (score 3):

Your link is wrong in the html you push to the new window. Use this instead

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"`
`href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/282/)